# Determined the PRIME numbers

Tags: c

Is it `1` & `0` are prime numbers ? because when i Input `1` & `0` it says that it is a PRIME

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int num, i,y = 0;

  printf("Enter a Number: ");
  scanf("%d",&num);

  for(i = 2; i <= num /2; ++i){

      if(num % i == 0){
          y=1;    
      }
  }

  printf("the number %d is a ",num);

  if (y == 0){
      printf("(PRIME)");
  }
  if(num % 2 == 0){
      printf("(EVEN)");

  }else
      printf("(ODD)");

  printf(" Number.");


}
```

can anybody help me with my code

Comment: 1 is obviously a prime number because it is divisible only by 1 and by itself. Concerning 0 look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539174/is-zero-a-prime-number

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Can you provide an authoritative source for `1` being prime? IIRC, Primes start from `2`. Otherwise prime factors would be an infinite list (not sure if that is the only reason, though).

Comment: This is a mathematical question which is hotly debated.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that neigher [0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is+0+prime+number%3F) nor [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is+1+prime+number%3F) is a prime number.

Comment: see also here: https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/one.html

Comment: @MikeCAT: `0` cannot be a prime, just by the definition. Also for the obvious reason it cannot be a **prime** factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, neither 0 nor 1 are considered to be prime numbers, that is, the lowest prime number is 2. You need to change the code into, for instance:

```
if (y == 0 && n >= 2)
```

this covers both 0 and 1 along with negative integers (thanks to @MikeCAT)

Comment: It should be `if (y == 0 && num >= 2)` because your code will also consider `-1` as prime number.

Comment: @mikeCat thanks for the correction i forgot that a prime numbers are always positive